# Scrollable Tab bar cannot restore when other tab clicked

Tags: android, scroll, tabs

**Problem 2:**
The Tab bar cannot restore back to original position when another tab is clicked (tab 1 with non-recyclerview). It sticked at the top until it can scrolls back using tab 2 that send it to the top

I'm using re-usable code that no need to re-write App Bar and Navigation Drawer everytime.

**Problem 1 detail:**
The app bar can scroll when scrolling recycler view but the tab bar is hiding behind app bar until app bar scroll out of the screen at top (tab bar cannot move and stay at 0 y-coordinate)

**Problem 1 (fixed):**
Solution: move the line "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" from viewpager to framelayout

[Motion 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk6X7.jpg) [motion 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTaCz.jpg)
←Screen capture
**My code are:**

activity_base.xml (acitivity to put every page in FrameLayout)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <!--Toolbar-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--Activity container to put page content-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!--
NavigationView - place inside drawer
-->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

pg02_push.xml (page with few tabs)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Pg02Push">
<!--
AppBarLayout > Toolbar, TabLayout
-->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    >

    <!--TabLayout-->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--VIewPager for Tab-->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

pg02tab02_allpush.xml (tab with recycler view)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.fcm.firsthandpptynoti.Pg02Tab02AllPush">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_tab02_allpush"

    android:divider="#FFB900"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

BaseActivity.java

```
    @Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID){
    /**
     * This is going to be our actual root layout.
     * Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.
     * It is never used directly. Instead, use getLayoutInflater() or
     * getSystemService(Class) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance
     * that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on
     * android.view.LayoutInflater#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    mDrawerLayoutFull = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    /**
     * {@link FrameLayout} to inflate the child's view. We could also use a {@link android.view.ViewStub}
     *
     */
    FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayoutFull.findViewById(R.id.flContent);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
    /**
     * Note that we don't pass the child's layoutId to the parent,
     * instead we pass it our inflated layout.
     */
    super.setContentView(mDrawerLayoutFull);

    /*
    Toolbar
    Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    */
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    if (useToolbar()) {
        mToolbar.setTitle(setTitleOnToolbar());
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
    else {
        mToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    /*
    Navigation View
    */
    //
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    //Navigation View
    setUpNavigationView();
    //....
    //...
    //..
    //.
}
//End of setContentView
```

Pg02Push.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pg02_push);

    /*
    Tab
    */
    //ViewPager - Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    //MyViewPagerAdapter
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
    //...
    //..
    //.

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    //Assigns the ViewPager to TabLayout
    //The one-stop shop for setting up this TabLayout with a ViewPager.
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

} // End of onCreate
```

Comment: The appbar can move after i removed linearlayout that wrapping the coordinatorlayout in activity_base.xml but tab bar is still sationary and behind app bar

Comment: Fixed part of the problem by moving "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" from viewpager to framelayout.